# Incremental Build of Nuget Packages

Tags: msbuild, nuget, msbuild-4.0

I want to execute an msbuild project which uses batching to determine that one or more `csproj` projects have been freshly-built, and therefore require fresh nuget packaging.  The script I've made so far seems like a reasonable start, but it the incremental-build mechanism isn't working.  The `MainBuild` target executes every time, no matter what.

Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="MainBuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Content>content\plugins\</Content>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Nuspec Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\plugins\*\*.nuspec" />
  </ItemGroup>

<Target Name="MainBuild"
        Inputs="%(Nuspec.RootDir)%(Nuspec.Directory)bin\$(Configuration)\*.dll"
        Outputs="%(Nuspec.RootDir)%(Nuspec.Directory)%(FileName).pkg" >
  <ItemGroup>
    <Inputs Include="%(Nuspec.RootDir)%(Nuspec.Directory)bin\$(Configuration)\*.dll" />
    <Outputs Include="%(Nuspec.RootDir)%(Nuspec.Directory)%(FileName).pkg" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message Text="INPUTS: %(Inputs.FullPath)" />
  <Message Text="OUTPUTS: @(Outputs->'%(FullPath)')" />

  <Copy SourceFiles="@(Inputs)" DestinationFiles="@(Outputs->'%(FullPath)')" />

</Target>
</Project>
```

The `Copy` task is just a debugging placeholder for calling-out to nuget and creating a new package.

The idea is that if any files in the `bin\Debug` directory are newer than the corresponding .nuspec file (found two folders above `bin\Debug`), then the `MainBuild` target should execute.

Any ideas?

p.s. The `Inputs` and `Outputs` attributes of the `Target` presumably each create an item.  I think it strange that the items created can't be referenced inside the target.  In the above example, I had to make a target-interna dynamic ItemGroup to re-create the items, just so that I could access them.  Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

I read this in the [MSBuild Batching documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx)

> If a task inside of a target uses batching, MSBuild needs to determine
>   if the inputs and outputs for each batch of items is up-to-date.
>   Otherwise, the target is executed every time it is hit.

Which may be the cuprit. Try changing your copy target to use batching instead of an ite transform (I don't think using item metadata in an item group satisfies the above requirement).

```
<Target Name="MainBuild"
        Inputs="%(Nuspec.RootDir)%(Nuspec.Directory)bin\$(Configuration)\*.dll"
        Outputs="%(Nuspec.RootDir)%(Nuspec.Directory)%(FileName).pkg" >
    <ItemGroup>
        <Inputs Include="%(Nuspec.RootDir)%(Nuspec.Directory)bin\$(Configuration)\*.dll" />
        <Outputs Include="%(Nuspec.RootDir)%(Nuspec.Directory)%(FileName).pkg" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="INPUTS: %(Inputs.FullPath)" />
    <Message Text="OUTPUTS: @(Outputs->'%(FullPath)')" />

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Inputs)" DestinationFiles="%(Outputs.FullPath)" />

</Target>
```

It looks like the number of inputs may be different than the number of outputs (I suspect there is more than one .dll files in the output directory for each project), which will also cause the target to execute.

Comment: After posting, I changed the target `Inputs` to have only one DLL.  That suddenly "fixed" the problem.  I'm left with the impression that the msbuild "incremental builds" mechanism is so primitive, that it perhaps should not be listed or publicized as a feature at all; seldom ever will an incremental build depend on a matching quantity of inputs and outputs.

Comment: Believe the problem here is that it doesn't support wildcards. Somehow you have to get the inputs into an item group which at first blush makes me thing batching is incompatible with incremental builds (aka inputs/outputs)